# Jquery easing doesnt work on font size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-easing

I would like to know if any of you have experienced this and workarounds employed if they exist.

When i use animate **normally** on font-size it works perfectly. However, when i use easing equations along with the animate function i get the following error message :

> Error: f.easing[e.animatedProperties[this.prop]] is not a function
>   Source File: https://192.168.1.218/jquery.js Line: 18

The following is the js code i have used :

```
$(".myclass").animate({"font-size" : "16px"},"easeOutBounce",200);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as indicated in the documentation for [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), you have to specify the easing argument after the duration, not before:

```
$(".myclass").animate({
    "font-size": "16px"
}, 200, "easeOutBounce");
```

However, that alone won't solve your problem. The `easeOutBounce` effect is not part of the jQuery core, you'll have to include an additional plugin like [jQuery Easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) or the [jQuery UI effects module](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html) to be able to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried this out - i think your easing argument is in the wrong place. This works for me

```
$(".myclass").animate({"font-size" : "16px"}, '200', 'easeOutBounce');
```